# How do i get tripinfo and detector file when i use OMnet++ with sumo?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to ask you some question about sumo and OMNet++. when i use the OMnet++ which  will run sumocfg  by itself,i cant get the detector file and tripinfo.I am doubtful of that.I would like to konw how to generate detector file and tripinfo after the OMNet++ has run out.

I have tried to get tripinfo and detector file .Each time , i run the sumocfg ,it generates detector file and tripinfo(I have added the additional detector file and tripinfo-output code).But i cant get the data after i run out OMNet++.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The veins launch daemon usually creates a temporary directory and copies the sumo config there. So it should use the same config you are using. Adding some more info about the commands you execute would indeed be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your help I forgot to reply. I have already figured out.